# Why is Bloc state not updating when using reactive_forms in flutter?

Tags: flutter, forms, bloc, flutter-bloc, flutter-reactive-forms

I am using flutter with `reactive_forms` package and BLoC. I tried to outsource the `FormGroup` to BLoC state class and providing it to the `ReactiveFormBuilder` using `BlocBuilder` widget.

Flutter Bloc - Profile State:

#### BLOC STATE

```dart
class ProfileState extends Equatable {
  final initAdditionalDocForm = FormGroup({
    "doc_images": FormControl(),
    "doc_number": FormControl(),
    "doc_type_id": FormControl()
  });
  final FormGroup initPersonalForm = FormGroup({
    'op_first_name': FormControl<String>(
        validators: [Validators.minLength(4), Validators.required]),
    'op_last_name': FormControl<String>(
        validators: [Validators.minLength(4), Validators.required]),
    'op_dob': FormControl<DateTime>(validators: [Validators.required]),
    'op_gender': FormControl<String>(
        validators: [Validators.required], value: "Not Specified"),
    'op_email': FormControl<String>(
        validators: [Validators.required, Validators.email]),
    'op_pet_name': FormControl<String>(),
    'op_mobile_no': FormControl<int>(validators: [
      Validators.number,
    ]),
    'op_alternate_mobile_no': FormControl<int>(validators: [
      Validators.number,
    ]),
    'veh_driving_license_no':
        FormControl<String>(validators: [Validators.required]),
    'veh_license_validity':
        FormControl<DateTime>(validators: [Validators.required]),
    'op_pan_no': FormControl<String>(),
    'AdditionalDoc': FormArray([]),
    'op_address_pin_code': FormControl<String>(
        validators: [Validators.required, Validators.number]),
    'op_address_state': FormControl<String>(validators: [Validators.required]),
    'op_address_city': FormControl<String>(validators: [Validators.required]),
    'op_address_line_1': FormControl<String>(validators: [Validators.required]),
    'op_address_line_2': FormControl<String>(),
    'op_landmark': FormControl<String>(),
    'op_profile': FormControl<String>() //Base 64 Profile Picture
  });

  static const _vehNoRegex =
      r"^[A-Z]{2}[ -][0-9]{1,2}(?: [A-Z])?(?: [A-Z]*)? [0-9]{4}$";

  final initVehicleInfoForm = FormGroup({
    //vehicle images maintained in the screen it self due to naming convention of API
    'veh_no_person': FormControl<int>(validators: [Validators.number]),
    'veh_charge_per_person':
        FormControl<int>(validators: [Validators.number, Validators.min(20)]),
    'veh_registration_no': FormControl<String>(
        validators: [Validators.pattern(_vehNoRegex), Validators.required]),
    'veh_city': FormControl<String>(validators: [Validators.required]),
    'veh_wheel_type': FormControl<int>(value: 4),
    'veh_capacity': FormControl<int>(),
    'veh_dimension': FormControl<String>(),
    'veh_color': FormControl<String>(validators: [Validators.required]),
    'veh_type':
        FormControl<int>(validators: [Validators.required], value: 1), //1 or 2
    'veh_fuel_type': FormControl<String>(validators: [Validators.required]),
    'veh_3km_15km': FormControl<int>(validators: [Validators.number]),
    'veh_above_15km': FormControl<int>(validators: [Validators.number]),
    'AdditionalDoc': FormArray([]),
  });

  final initBusinessProfileForm = FormGroup({
    'doc_pan':
        FormControl<String>(validators: [Validators.required]), //Base64 Image
    'op_bu_address_city':
        FormControl<String>(validators: [Validators.required]),
    'op_bu_address_line_1':
        FormControl<String>(validators: [Validators.required]),
    'op_bu_address_line_2':
        FormControl<String>(validators: [Validators.required]),
    'op_bu_address_pin_code':
        FormControl<int>(validators: [Validators.required]),
    'op_bu_address_state':
        FormControl<String>(validators: [Validators.required]),
    'op_payment_mode': FormControl<String>(validators: [Validators.required]),
    'op_bu_email': FormControl<String>(
        validators: [Validators.required, Validators.email]),
    'op_bu_gstn_available':
        FormControl<bool>(validators: [Validators.required]),
    'op_bu_gstn_no': FormControl<String>(validators: [Validators.required]),
    'op_bu_landmark': FormControl<String>(validators: [Validators.required]),
    'op_bu_name': FormControl<String>(validators: [Validators.required]),
    'op_bu_pan_no': FormControl<String>(validators: [Validators.required]),
    'AdditionalDoc': FormArray([])
  });

  ///Bank Details
  final initPaymentInfoForm = FormGroup({
    'op_bank_name': FormControl<String>(validators: [Validators.required]),
    'op_bank_ifsc': FormControl<String>(validators: [Validators.required]),
    'op_bank_account_number':
        FormControl<int>(validators: [Validators.required]),
  });

  late final FormGroup personalProfileForm;
  late final FormGroup personalProfileAdditionalDocGroup;
  late final FormGroup vehicleInfoForm;
  late final FormGroup businessProfileForm;
  late final FormGroup paymentInfoForm;

  ProfileState({
    FormGroup? personalForm,
    FormGroup? additionalDoc,
    FormGroup? vehicleForm,
    FormGroup? businessForm,
    FormGroup? paymentForm,
  }) : super() {
    personalProfileAdditionalDocGroup = additionalDoc ?? initAdditionalDocForm;
    personalProfileForm = personalForm ?? initPersonalForm;
    vehicleInfoForm = vehicleForm ?? initVehicleInfoForm;
    businessProfileForm = businessForm ?? initBusinessProfileForm;
    paymentInfoForm = paymentForm ?? initPaymentInfoForm;
  }

  @override
  List<Object> get props => [
        personalProfileForm,
        personalProfileAdditionalDocGroup,
        businessProfileForm,
        vehicleInfoForm,
        paymentInfoForm,
      ];

  ProfileState copyWith({
    FormGroup? personalForm,
    FormGroup? additionalDoc,
    FormGroup? vehicleForm,
    FormGroup? businessForm,
    FormGroup? paymentForm,
  }) =>
      ProfileState(
        personalForm: personalForm ?? personalProfileForm,
        additionalDoc: additionalDoc ?? personalProfileAdditionalDocGroup,
        vehicleForm: vehicleInfoForm,
        businessForm: businessProfileForm,
        paymentForm: paymentInfoForm,
      );
}
```

#### BLOC Method

Inside the main Bloc Class there is a event method which is fired when the form is filled.

```dart
 Future<void> _onSaveProfile(ProfileEvent event, Emitter emit) async {
    try {
      emit(ProfileSaving());
      if (event is SaveProfileData) {
        state.copyWith(personalForm: event.personalProfile);
      }

      emit(ProfileSaved());
    } catch (e) {
      print(e);
    }
  }
```

#### UI Widget

The reactive form builder is:

```dart
BlocBuilder<ProfileBloc, ProfileState>(
      builder: (context, state) {
        return ReactiveFormBuilder(
          form: () => state.personalProfileForm,
          builder: (context, form, _) => ListView(
            children: [
              /* First & Last Name */
              profileRowBuilder(
                context,
                const ReactiveTextFieldCustomV1(
                  formControlName: "op_first_name",
                  hintText: "",
                  showLabel: true,
                  labelText: "First Name",
                  shortHeight: true,
                ),
   ........
ElevatedButton(
                onPressed: () {
                  
                  context
                      .read<ProfileBloc>()
                      .add(SaveProfileData(personalProfile: form));
                  // print(
                  //     state.personalProfileForm.control('op_first_name').value);
                  // print(_drivingLicenseNo);
                },
                child: Text("Press"),
              ),
              ElevatedButton(
                onPressed: () {
                  print(
                      state.personalProfileForm.control('op_first_name').value);
                  // state.personalProfileForm.controls.forEach((key, value) {
                  //   print("$key: ${value.value}");
                  // });
                },
                child: Text("State"),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        );
      },
    );
  }
```

The first button is firing the event and I am passing the entire form to the event and as shown in the `_onProfileSave()` method, it is copied to state. But the form values which are typed in the textfield are `null` when I click the 2nd button to view the state.

Would be great to receive a solution. Also would be great to receive any suggestions on how to use reactive_forms with BLoC.

I tried to debug it and check via VS Code debugger, but the `form` inside of ReactiveBuilder there are values but when the event is fired, in the state the form values are still `null`. They are not copied.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As bloc requires an event to be fired when updating the state, it had to fire an event when then form changes and use `.copyWith` (if you have it setup). As this overhead is not necessary in Cubits, it works with cubits. So I generally follow Cubits for such use cases and Blocs for others like auth etc.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe is not emitting the new state because they are `==`. Same thing happened to me recently with `FormGroup` i solved with this

`emit(state.copyWith(FormGroup(event.controls)));`

Comment: When I migrated the same thing to cubits it was working fine. Will try out your solution. Thank you